# Faut-il accorder le participe passé avec un complément objet direct spécifié suivi de « que » ?

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé

Je sais que si on a un objet direct comme *le*, *la*, *etc* il faut accorder  le participe passé avec le complément d'objet direct.

L'accord est-il nécessaire avec les objets comme : « **La voiture** que j'ai conduite » ?

Dans [cette leçon](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/French/Lessons/Agreement_of_past_participles_with_avoir) il est expliqué que si un objet précède le verbe, il faut accorder, alors je pense que la réponse est oui. Est-ce correct ? Y a-t-il d'autres cas où il faut accorder le participe passé avec le complément d'objet direct ?