# "Elle a rencontré" or "elle a rencontrée"?

Tags: grammaire, genre, accord

I have to write the sentence:

> En chemin, elle rencontre un loup qui a faim.

in the past. Should I translate to "elle a rencontré" or "elle a rencontrée" and why?

> En chemin, elle a rencontré(e) un loup qui avait a faim.

Comment: Related question here: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1971/79

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

> Elle a rencontré

the always valid rule is that with *avoir* for auxiliary, there is no agreement, as opposed to *être*. Here, *a* is from *avoir*, therefore no need to agree. But be careful, because if she met a feminine noun and you want to specify this, you could also say

> Elle l'a rencontrée

Meaning 'she met her', in which case you have to agree the ending.  Because the "l'" is a *complément objet direct* (COD) placed *before* the verbal phrase, and if there is a COD before *avoir* used as an auxiliary you have to agree the verb with it.  Similarly « *Elle les a rencontrées* » if she met a group of feminine things.

Answer (score 3):

"Elle a rencontré" is correct, because agreement with the past participle is only used when

- Conjugating with *être*
- Agreeing with preceding direct object