# Pas d'accord pour « se rendre compte de » et « se plaire/complaire »

Tags: accord, verbes-pronominaux

À la page 28 dans *Advanced French Grammar*, V. Mazet présente ceci :

> Some pronomial verbs don't exist in a non-pronominal form. As a result, you can't determine if the pronoun *se* is a direct object or an indirect object. What to do about the agreement ? In general, make the past participle agree with the *se*. Exceptions are: **se rendre compte de** and **se plaire/se complaire**. The past participles *rendu* and *plu/complu* always remain invariable.

Pourquoi les verbes *se rendre compte de* et *se plaire/se complaire* se démarquent-ils comme des exceptions à l'accord ? Un exemple de Voltaire :

> Je vous en félicite, et j'implore la nature universelle qu'elle daigne conserver long-temps ce réservoir de pensées heureuses dans lequel elle s'est **complu**.

J'ai consulté [Faut-il accorder le participe passé avec un complément objet direct spécifié suivi de « que » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/faut-il-accorder-le-participe-passe-avec-un-complement-objet-direct-specifie-sui?lq=1).

---

**Un supplément dû à la réponse de Circeus :**

1. Pourriez-vous expliciter pourquoi est-ce que *s’approprier* est membre de l’ensemble des verbes pour lesquels le participe passé ne s'accorde pas avec l’objet direct ? Un exemple de Isabelle de Montolieu :

   > A. La langue anglaise **s’est appropriée** notre vieux mot de désappointement (disappointed).
2. Si je reformulais le deuxième groupe, je le décrirais comme des verbes dont le pronom réflexif est un objet indirect. Alors, d’après ce qui suit, pourquoi les verbes *s’arroger* et *se complaire* en sont-ils membres ?

   Un exemple tiré de la *Réimpression de l'ancien moniteur*, éditions H. Plon :

   > B. On se flatte encore que la cour de Vienne et celle de Berlin auront assez de courage pour ne pas souscrire à l’orgueilleuse prééminence que l’impératrice de Russe **s’est arrogée** dans le partage.

   Un exemple des *Œuvres complètes de Saint Jean Chrysostôme* :

   > C. Et toute cette économie divine est-elle le résultat de la volonté exclusive du Fils ? Non, c'est aussi avec la participation du Père céleste, comme l’a soigneusement exprîmé le Prophète par ces mots : Mon bien aimé en qui **s’est complue** mon âme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les verbes qui font partie de ce groupe sont généralement:

1. soit des verbes où la construction permet/exige un complément direct.
   Par exemple, dans *rendre compte*, c'est *compte* qui est en fait le complément avec lequel le participe passé devrait s'accorder! *s'approprier* est un autre exemple.
2. soit des verbes dont la forme non pronominale a **un objet indirect** que remplace le pronom réfléchi, avec lequel le participe passé ne peut donc pas s'accorder. Par exemple, *se* remplace un complément indirect introduit par *à*. En d'autres termes, *succéder/arroger/complaire à qqun* équivalent à *se succéder*, *s'arroger*, *se complaire*. Parfois la forme d'origine non pronominale est tombée en désuétude (comme dans le cas d'*arroger* et de *complaire*).

**Ajout**

Il ne faut pas confondre ces 2 groupes de verbes! À propos du second groupe, *se succéder* ne peut jamais avoir de complément d'objet direct. C'est pourquoi son participe passé *succédé* est invariable.

Les verbes du premier groupe peuvent accorder le participe passé, mais **avec un complément d'objet qui n'est pas le sujet (contrairement à un verbe comme *s'envoler* ou *se laver*)**. En outre, il y a une forte tendance à accorder ces verbes toujours avec le sujet (tendance qui fut à une époque la règle). Bien entendu, la complexité des règles elle-même n'est pas pour diminuer la fréquence des erreurs!

Dans les 3 accords que vous donnez, il n'y en a qu'un qui soit, selon moi, correct: A, celui de s'arroger (accordé correctement avec le COD *prééminence*).
Dans B, le COD « notre vieux mot » est après le verbe et donc il ne devrait **pas** y avoir d'accord.
Dans C, le verbe *se complaire* ne devrait jamais s'accorder, mais à mon avis c'est un verbe tellement rare que l'erreur est plutôt excusable.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne mettrais simplement pas ces verbes dans la classe des verbes essentiellement pronominaux : [*rendre compte de qqch à qqun*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/compte), [*plaire à qqun*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/plaire), [*complaire à qqun*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/complaire) existent.